# Twitter API Fail

Tags: php, twitter

I have the following two files

sendTweet.php

```
<?php

require_once('twitteroauth.php');
require_once('OAuth.php');

session_start();

$consumer_key = '!!!'; 
$consumer_secret = '!!!';
$connection = new TwitterOAuth ($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken();

$_SESSION ['Oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION ['Oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];


switch ($connection->http_code) {
case 200:
$url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL ($token);
header ('Location:'. $url);
break;
default:
echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}

?>
```

And my callback, followthru.php

```
    <?php
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
require_once('OAuth.php');
session_start();

$consumer_key = '!!!'; 
$consumer_secret = '!!!';

if (isset ($_REQUEST ['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION ['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST ['oauth_token']) {
$_SESSION ['Oauth_status'] = 'oldtoken';
}

$connection = new TwitterOAuth ($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $_SESSION ['oauth_token'], $_SESSION ['oauth_token_secret']);

$access_token = $connection-> getAccessToken ($_REQUEST ['oauth_verifier']);

$_SESSION ['access_token'] = $access_token;

$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
print_r($content);
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Text of status here'));
if (200 == $connection->http_code) {
echo 'Success!';
 // $_SESSION ['status'] =  'verified';
} else {
}
?>
```

Followthru.php echo's:

```
stdClass Object ( [request] => /1/account/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=pIkRdkUVhiKPiw32S2zbA&oauth_nonce=1e6bfcdaf50c2213219341105edd353c&oauth_signature=qNJ8g1i9eXZEM%2FgbTHLxMpkHZmg%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1296010545&oauth_token=&oauth_version=1.0 [error] => Could not authenticate you. )
```

It is stating that it cannot authenticate me? I am completly confused and would love if you guys helped me.

Comment: No idea. But maybe you can find a similar error result with one of the previous Twitter and OAuth help requests here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter+php+oauth

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing some parts of the code..

`new TwitterOAuth ($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $_SESSION ['oauth_token'], $_SESSION ['oauth_token_secret']);`

Where are those $_SESSION vars defined?

Perhaps this snippet can help you a bit with the order in which you need to do some things:

```
  if (isset($_GET['oauth_token'])) {
        $Twitter->setToken($_GET['oauth_token']);
        $token = $Twitter->getAccessToken();
        $Twitter->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);
        $user= $Twitter->get_accountVerify_credentials();
}
```

Comment: Hate to ask and sound dumb but what file do I put that in?

Comment: You shouldn't just copy it, but try to understand in what order you should do things. In your snippets you are creating a connection with tokens that you haven't requested yet.